# How to disable the message “Are you sure you want to send a form again” when using twitter's new widget?

Tags: html, forms, widget, twitter

I've just added twitter's new widget to my web site.

It's always displayed in side menu, and side menu is set up everywhere in my web site.

However with Safari it always pops up this message when I go back to previous page.

```
Are you sure you want to send a form again?
```

I think the post method in that comment form is doing that.
How can I customize and hide that message to everyone who is seeing my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just remove the form re-submission message. You can make it post to a separate page and then redirect the user back though.

Comment: Thanks then I'll give up on this since it only happens with MacOSX's safari